# An identity of an Elliptical Integral

Tags: integration, elliptic-integrals

> Suppose $0<k<1$ and $\displaystyle
>  K(k)=\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-k^2x^2)}}$. Let
>    $\tilde{k}$ be $\tilde{k}^2=1-k^2$. Show that $$\displaystyle
>  K(k)=\frac{2}{1+\tilde{k}}K\left(\frac{1-\tilde{k}}{1+\tilde{k}}\right)$$

There's a hint in *Stein's Complex Analysis* which is this change of variable : $x=\dfrac{2t}{1+\tilde{k}+(1-\tilde{k})t^2}$.

Comment: Seems like you can find your answer here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/811444/how-to-integrate-int-0-pi-frac1-sqrt1k2-sin2-phi-d-phi. Exact same question just now in the trigonometric form.

Comment: That's a bit similar but not same !

Comment: It's actually a particular case of the hypergeometric identity $$_{2}F_{1} \Big( a, a + \frac{1}{2} - b,;b+ \frac{1}{2};z^{2}\Big) = (1+z)^{-2a} \ _{2}F_{1} \Big(a,b;2b;\frac{4z}{(1+z)^{2}} \Big)$$

Comment: Apart from two typos in your last expression, you are actually pretty close to prove the identity yourself.
$$\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{1-\tilde{k}}{1+\tilde{k}}\right)^2t^4-\frac{ 2\tilde{k}^2t^2 + 2t^2}{\color{red}{(1+\tilde{k})^2}} }
= \sqrt{(1-t^2)\left(1-\left(\frac{1-\tilde{k}}{1+\tilde{k}}\right)^2t^2\right)}$$
$$\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{1-\tilde{k}}{1+\tilde{k}}\right)^2t^4+\frac{ 2\tilde{k}^2t^2 - 2t^2}{\color{red}{(1+\tilde{k})^2}}}
= 1-\left(\frac{1-\tilde{k}}{1-\tilde{k}}\right)t^2 $$

Comment: Oh my god ... thank you ... you saved me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(*)\displaystyle\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}=2\times\frac{1+\tilde{k}+(1-\tilde{k})t^2-2(1-\tilde{k})t^2}{[1+\tilde{k}+(1-\tilde{k})t^2]^2}=2\frac{1+\tilde{k}-(1-\tilde{k})t^2}{[1+\tilde{k}+(1-\tilde{k})t^2]^2}$.

$(*)\displaystyle\sqrt{1-x^2}=\frac{\sqrt{(1+\tilde{k})^2+(1-\tilde{k})^2t^4+2k^2t^2-4t^2}}{1+\tilde{k}+(1-\tilde{k})t^2}=\frac{\sqrt{(1+\tilde{k})^2+(1-\tilde{k})^2t^4-2\tilde{k}^2t^2-2t^2}}{1+\tilde{k}+(1-\tilde{k})t^2}$.

$(*)\displaystyle\sqrt{1-k^2x^2}=\frac{\sqrt{(1+\tilde{k})^2+(1-\tilde{k})^2t^4+2k^2t^2-4k^2t^2}}{1+\tilde{k}+(1-\tilde{k})t^2}=\frac{\sqrt{(1+\tilde{k})^2+(1-\tilde{k})^2t^4-2k^2t^2}}{1+\tilde{k}+(1-\tilde{k})t^2}$.

Now by reparameterizing the Integral :

$\begin{align*}
\displaystyle K(k)&=2\int_0^1\frac{1+\tilde{k}+(1-\tilde{k})t^2}{\sqrt{(1+\tilde{k})^2+(1-\tilde{k})^2t^4-2\tilde{k}^2t^2-2t^2}}.
\frac{1+\tilde{k}+(1-\tilde{k})t^2}{\sqrt{(1+\tilde{k})^2+(1-\tilde{k})^2t^4-2k^2t^2}}\\
&\qquad.\frac{1+\tilde{k}-(1-\tilde{k})t^2}{[1+\tilde{k}+(1-\tilde{k})t^2]^2}.\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac{2}{1+\tilde{k}}\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(\frac{1-\tilde{k}}{1+\tilde{k}})^2t^4-\frac{2\tilde{k}^2t^2+2t^2}{\color{red}{(1+\tilde{k})^2}} }}.
\frac{1-(\frac{1-\tilde{k}}{1+\tilde{k}})t^2}{\sqrt{1+(\frac{1-\tilde{k}}{1+\tilde{k}})^2t^4+\frac{2\tilde{k}^2t^2-2t^2}{\color{red}{(1+\tilde{k})^2}}}}\mathrm{d}t
\end{align*}$

Here is the Complete proof after [achille hui](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/59379/achille-hui)'s correction:

$\begin{align*}
\displaystyle LHS&=\frac{2}{1+\tilde{k}}\int_0^1 \frac{1-(\frac{1-\tilde{k}}{1+\tilde{k}})t^2}
{\sqrt{(1-t^2)\left(1-\frac{1-\tilde{k}}{1-\tilde{k}}t^2\right)}.\sqrt{\left(1-(\frac{1-\tilde{k}}{1+\tilde{k}})t^2\right)^2}}\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\displaystyle\frac{2}{1+\tilde{k}}\int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm{d}t}
{\sqrt{(1-t^2)\left(1-\frac{1-\tilde{k}}{1-\tilde{k}}t^2\right)}}\\
&=\displaystyle\frac{2}{1+\tilde{k}}K\left(\frac{1-\tilde{k}}{1+\tilde{k}}\right)\tag{QED}
\end{align*}$

Answer (score 13):

For me, the only way I can remember this sort of complicated identities is through the relationship between the 
[complete elliptic integral of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind)
 $K(k)$ and the corresponding [arithmetic-geometric mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean).

$$K(k) = \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\theta}} = \frac{\pi}{2\text{AGM}( 1, \sqrt{1-k^2})}\tag{*1}$$

Consider following integral

$$I(a,b) = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}
\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{a^2\cos^2\theta + b^2\sin^2\theta}}$$
Introduce $x = b\tan\theta$, we can rewrite it as

$$I(a,b) = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{d\tan\theta}{
\sqrt{(1+\tan^2\theta)(a^2+b^2\tan^2\theta})}
= \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x^2 + a^2)(x^2+b^2)}}\tag{*2}$$
Substitute $x$ by $\sqrt{ab} t$, we have
$$I(a,b) 
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{ab}}\int_0^\infty \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^4 + \left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}\right)t^2 + 1}}
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{ab}}\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{ ( t - t^{-1})^2 + \frac{(a+b)^2}{ab}}}\frac{dt}{t}
$$
Notice the last integrand is invariant under transform $\displaystyle\;t \leftrightarrow \frac{1}{t}$. If we introduce two more variables $s$ and $y$ such that
$$s = \frac12 (t - t^{-1}) = \frac{y}{\sqrt{ab}}$$ and using the fact $$\frac{dt}{t} = \frac{d(t - t^{-1})}{t + t^{-1}} = \frac{ds}{\sqrt{s^2+1}}$$
We can rewrite $I(a,b)$ as
$$
\frac{2}{\sqrt{ab}}\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{ ( t - t^{-1})^2 + \frac{(a+b)^2}{ab}}}\frac{dt}{t}
= \frac{2}{\sqrt{ab}}\int_0^\infty 
\frac{ds}{\sqrt{\left(4s^2 + \frac{(a+b)^2}{ab}\right)(s^2+1)}}\\
= \int_0^\infty 
\frac{dy}{\sqrt{\left(y^2 + \left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2\right)(y^2 + ab)}}
$$
Compare this with $(*2)$, we obtain an important identity:
$$I(a,b) = I\left(\frac{a+b}{2}, \sqrt{ab}\right)$$
This means $I(a,b)$ is invariant if we replace $(a,b)$ by their AM and GM.

Start with any pair of numbers $a,b$, it is well known if you repeat taking AM/GM of them,
the pairs will ultimately converge to a single number. This is called the arithmetic geometric mean of $a$ and $b$ and usually denoted as  $\text{AGM}(a,b)$. If one replace $a$, $b$ by this AGM in the definition of $I(a,b)$, we obtain

$$I(a,b) = \frac{\pi}{2\text{AGM}(a,b)}$$

Together with the obvious identity $K(k) = I(1,\sqrt{1-k^2})$, we immediately obtain $(*1)$.

Using these tools and notice $\text{AGM}(a,b)$ is homogenous. i.e.

$$\text{AGM}(\lambda a, \lambda b) = \lambda \text{AGM}(a,b) \quad\implies\quad I(\lambda a, \lambda b) = \frac{1}{\lambda} I(a,b),$$ 
the desired identity follows immediately.

$$
K(k) 
= I(1,\tilde{k}) = I\left(\frac{1+\tilde{k}}{2},\sqrt{\tilde{k}}\right) = \frac{2}{1+\tilde{k}} I\left(1,2\frac{\sqrt{\tilde{k}}}{1+\tilde{k}}\right)\\
= \frac{2}{1+\tilde{k}} K\left( \sqrt{1 - \frac{4\tilde{k}}{(1+\tilde{k})^2}} \right)
= \frac{2}{1+\tilde{k}} K\left( \frac{1-\tilde{k}}{1+\tilde{k}} \right)
$$

Comment: complicated but very very interesting .. thank you so much

Comment: A nice description about Landen's transform! (+1)

Comment: Very nice. See also: JM Borwein and PB Borwein ”The arithmetic-geometric mean and fast computation of elementary
functions”, SIAM V26, 351 (1984)