# Value of an elliptic integral of the first kind

Tags: special-functions, math-history, elliptic-integrals

The elliptic integral of the first kind
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}{\frac{du}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2{u}}}}
$$
cannot be expressed in terms of standard functions. But in the following context from [The Pendulum](http://books.google.com/books?id=cCYkPwAACAAJ) by Baker the author says

[image: A part of the Pendulum by Baker]

What is the meaning of the **Its value** in the above context? Can the elliptic integral be expressed in terms of standard functions?

Comment: No, they probably just mean that it's form was first found then or some numerical computations were performed.

Comment: We just know so much integral-shaped identities about **Elliptic Integrals**.
For this case, it's also interpreted as $\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-k^2x^2)}}$ which is similar to Christoffel Integrals which map Complex Upper Half Plane to polygens:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/813698/an-identity-of-an-elliptical-integral