# An identity for the complete elliptic integral of the first kind

Tags: elliptic-integrals

On the Wolfram webpage, one can find the following identity for the complete elliptic integal of the first kind $K(z)$:

$$K(z) = \frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-z}} K\Big( \Big( \frac{1-\sqrt{1-z}}{1+\sqrt{1-z}} \Big)^2 \Big)$$

See http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticK/17/01/0007/.

Does anyone have a good reference for this (I checked the DLMF and Abramowitz/Stegun, but did not find anything). Or is there a simple proof that I am missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at Borwein/Borwein's *Pi and the AGM*?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will check. BTW, I can actually prove it: one shows that the two sides satisfy the same second-order DE (substituting $\sqrt{1-z} = x$ first helps with calculations) with the same initial values for x=1 resp. z=0. But that does not seem particularly elegant...

Comment: look at this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/813951/59379) which uses [AGM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean) to prove this identity (note: Mathematica is using a different convention for $K(z)$,  $K(z) = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1 - z\sin^2\theta}}$, the $z$ it uses is really the $k^2$ in other refs)

Comment: @achillehui Why does that not come as a surprise....?

Comment: That does settle it, thanks. Somehow this answer escaped me when I was searching through StackExchange.