# Arithmetic mean geometric mean 2d map

Tags: numerical-methods, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, elliptic-integrals

Consider the 2d iteration
\begin{aligned}
    x_{n+1} &=\frac{x_n+y_n}2,\\
    y_{n+1} &=\sqrt{x_ny_n}.
\end{aligned}
We assume that $x_0>y_0>0$. Hence, $x_n>x_{n+1}>y_{n+1}>y_n$ due to the AM-GM inequality.
Since the sequence $x_n$ is bounded from below and decreases monotonically,
there is a limit $x_\infty$. Also, $y_n$ grows monotonically and is bounded
from above. Hence, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}y_n=y_\infty$.
We also know that
$$
x_{n+1}-y_{n+1}=
\frac{(\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{y_n})^2}2=\frac12\frac{\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{y_n}}{\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt{y_n}}(x_n-y_n)<\frac12(x_n-y_n)<2^{-n-1}(x_0-y_0).
$$
Therefore, we find that both sequences have the same limit $L(x_0, y_0)=x_\infty=y_\infty$.

1. I cannot find the fixed-point $(x^*, y^*)$ of the iteration above, since both
   equations yield only $x^*=y^*$.
   I wonder if there is an analytic expression for $L(x_0, y_0)$ or at least an
   aproximate expression.
2. In the paper by Borwein and Borwein "The arithmetic-geometric mean and fast
   computation of elementary functions", SIAM V26, 351 (1984), they claim that
   elliptic integral of the second kind
   $$
   I(a,b)= \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{a^2\cos^2\theta+b^2\sin^2\theta}},
   $$
   where $I(a,b)=I(L(a,b))=\frac{\pi}{2L(a,b)}$.
   By numerical integration, I got something else though.
   **Edit:** I fixed this numerical problem, it was a bug in my code. I added the code below. Unfortunately, it seems the code formatting tool of math stackexchange is not working properly.

> import numpy as np
>
> ```
> import scipy.integrate
>
> from scipy.special import ellipk
>
> a = 2.0
>
> b = 1.0
>
> x = a
>
> y = b
>
> ###########################################################
>
> def fun(x, a, b):
>
>   f = 1.0/np.sqrt((a*np.cos(x))**2+(b*np.sin(x))**2)
>
>   return f
>
> ###########################################################
>
> def fun2(x, m):
>
>   f = 1.0/np.sqrt(1-m*(np.sin(x))**2)
>
>   return f
>
> ##########################################################
>
> integral, err = scipy.integrate.quad(fun,0., np.pi/2,args=(a,b,))
>
> print('Original Gaussian quadrature integral', integral)
>
> for i in range(100):
>
>   plt.plot(x, y, 'ro', ms=2.0)
>
>   x_n = (x+y)/2
>
>   y_n = np.sqrt(x*y)
>
>   x = x_n
>
> L = x
>
> print('iteration result', np.pi/(2*L))
>
> m = 1-(b/a)**2
>
> Im = ellipk(m)/a
>
> print('ellipk', Im)
>
> integral, err = scipy.integrate.quad(fun2, 0., np.pi/2,args=(m,))
>
> print('Gaussian quadrature integral', integral/a)
> ```

3. How to show that $I(a, b)=I\left(\frac{a+b}2, \sqrt{ab}\right)$?

According to the authors, this problem has a long history, dating back to Gauss and Legendre.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/813698

Comment: That covers item 3. Thanks! Item 2 might be a bug in my code. I would like to add it here, but for some reason the code formatting did not work.

Comment: See as well https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2009/08/pi-and-the-agm-evaluating-elliptic-integrals.html#.YZRD8mDMLIU

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is your question in 1... it is clear that all points $(x^*,x^*)$ are fixed points of the underlying map. Another issue is to decide, for any particular $(x_0,y_0)$, if the sequence is converging, and to which of these fixed points.

In the picture bellow you can find the contour plots of $(x_0,y_0)\mapsto L(x_0,y_0)$, i.e. initial approximations in the same contour lead to convergence to the same fixed point.

[image]

Comment: I think I showed the iteration converges in my OP.  The problem is to determine the limit $L(x_0, y_0)$ for $x_0>y_0>0$. I can only do that numerically. I believe there is no analytical expression, since it is directly related to the complete elliptic integral of the first kind.

Comment: @minmax I attached a figure to my post. It seems that the attracting set for each fixed point is a hyperbolic type curve.

Comment: thanks! but I think don't understand your figure. Are these curves level sets? The function $L(a,b)$ is homogenous, that is $L(\lambda a, \lambda b)=\lambda L(a, b)$. I think this could help. I just added the simple code I used to verify the theory.

Comment: @minmax If you pick $(x_0,y_0)$ and use it as initial approximation for the fixed point method, you will observe convergence to some point $(x_*(x_0,y_0), x_*(x_0,y_0))$. The picture represents the contours of $f(x_0,y_0)= x_*(x_0,y_0)$. For instance, points on the contour level 2 produce sequences converging to $(2,2)$.